# Find branches F, G of log(z), both analytic at 1 and i, such that: Im F(1) > Im F(i) Im G(1) > Im G(i)

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts

Find branches F, G of log(z), both analytic at 1 and i, such that: 
Im F(1) > Im F(i) 
Im G(1) > Im G(i)

I think I know how to do it, I'm just little confused about what "branches" mean.
When it says branches, does it mean in the form log theta (z), 0

Comment: It would be worth your time (and your readers') if you learn to convert things into LaTex: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Let $z=re^{i\theta}$; then $\log z=\log r+i\theta$. The trouble is that $\theta$ is ambiguous, so when we make it *unambiguous* by imposing a condition such as $0\leq\theta<2\pi$ we get a specific "branch" of the logarithm corresponding to that condition. Can you find which branches are appropriate here?